# No such file or directory at /cgi-bin/upload.pl line 26. When trying to upload a file using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, apache, perl

This is my HTML Code.

```
<button class="button" ngf-select ng-model="files" ngf-multiple="multiple">Select File</button>

Files:
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="f in files" style="font:smaller">{{f.name}}</li>
</ul>
Upload Log:
<pre>{{log}}</pre>
```

This is controller code.

```
$scope.$watch('files', function () {
    $scope.upload($scope.files);
});
$scope.log = '';

$scope.upload = function (files) {
    if (files && files.length) {
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            var file = files[i];
            Upload.upload({
                url: '/cgi-bin/upload.pl',
                fields: {
                    'username': $scope.username
                },
                file: file
            }).progress(function (evt) {
                var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
                $scope.log = 'progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% ' +
                            evt.config.file.name + '\n' + $scope.log;
            }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $timeout(function() {
                    $scope.log = 'file: ' + config.file.name + ', Response: ' + JSON.stringify(data) + '\n' + $scope.log;
                });
            })
            .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                alert ('Error');
            });

        }
    }
};
```

This is Perl script.

```
#!c:/perl64/bin/perl.exe

use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;
use CGI::Carp qw(warningsToBrowser fatalsToBrowser);
use CGI;
use CGI qw(:standard);
use JSON;
use CGI::Carp qw ( fatalsToBrowser );
use File::Basename;

#send the obligatory Content-Type
print "Content-Type: text/html\n\n"; 

$CGI::POST_MAX = 1024 * 5000;
my $safe_filename_characters = "a-zA-Z0-9_.-";

my $cgi = new CGI();
my $upload_dir = "../images"; #location on our server  
my $filename = "dummy.png";

my $upload_filehandle = $cgi->upload("file");
print $upload_filehandle;

open UPLOADFILE, ">../..$upload_dir$filename"  or die $!;
binmode UPLOADFILE;

while ( <$upload_filehandle> )
{
    print UPLOADFILE;
}
close UPLOADFILE;
```

When i trying to upload the file on local Apache server, seeing this error.

No such file or directory at C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Group/Apache2/htdocs/admin/cgi-bin/upload.pl line 26.

This is line 26 in perl script.

```
open UPLOADFILE, ">../..$upload_dir$filename"  or die $!;
```

I have a folder named images already created. So why this error?

Can anyone help me what is wrong, and what chages are needed to that i can upload the file properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$upload_dir` is `../images`, and

`$filename` is `dummy.png`, so

`"../..$upload_dir$filename"` is `../..../imagesdummy.png`.

Need I say more?

That's why it's good to include the path in the error message.

```
my $qfn = "../..$upload_dir$filename";
open(my $UPLOADFILE, '>', $qfn)
   or die("Can't create \"$qfn\": $!\n");
```

(Note that I made other improvements, including switching from global glob `UPLOADFILE` to lexical scalar `$UPLOADFILE` for the file handle. You'll have to adjust the following code to use that scalar if you adopt this highly recommended practice.)

Comment: Hi ikegami. Thanks for the response. After integrating your suggested cahnegs now i am getting this error. Can't create ../..../imagesdummy.png;

Comment: As it should. Do you really think the path `../..../imagesdummy.png` makes sense?

Comment: Oops My fault. I made the changes. 
my $qfn = "../$upload_dir/$filename";
my $UPLOADFILE;

open($UPLOADFILE, '>', $qfn)
   or die("Can't create \"$qfn\": $!\n");    Now response is file: als.png, Response: "als.png", But no file is saving in directory. Any idea, what's wrong now?

Comment: But i am still using my $UPLOADFILE;  (global). But file is not saving in designated directory.

Comment: 1) That's not global. `my` variables are lexically scoped. 2) Just to be clear, you are using `$UPLOADFILE` every now? 3) Well, where is it failing? Does `open` give an error message? it creating an empty file? Is the loop being entered?

Comment: Open Not giving any error. And also flow entering into the loop. But file is not getting created. (Not even empty file)

Comment: If `open` succeeded, the file got created. You must be looking at the wrong location. Remember, the current working directory is not necessarily the directory in which the script is located.

Comment: Yes. Its creating a empty file. (0 Byte), what can be the reason its not dumping data there.

Comment: oh, `print $UPLOADFILE;` will actually print something like `GLOB(0x4b5d94)` to STDOUT (Why didn't you mention you saw this?) You'll need to explicitly specify `$_`: `print $UPLOADFILE $_;`

Comment: No i didn't saw that. Thank you so much for helping me. Its creating a file now in directory. But when i am trying to open its showing invalid image. I think still there is some more thing that i m missing.

Comment: Thanks alot. Issue is solved now. I was doing 
binmode UPLOADFILE; instead 
binmode $UPLOADFILE;..

Comment: yeah, I wasn't kidding when I said you'd need to change the rest of your code to use `$UPLOADFILE` instead of `UPLOADFILE`. They are two different variables.